# detect mobile device with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add some javascript code to the headline of a mobile website to detect the device model so when someone gets on my landing page using a samsung galaxy it would detect it and say some text like "your "samsung galaxy" etc etc" is there anyway i can go about doing this with javascript?

Comment: Check the userAgent property of the window's navigator object.

Comment: It sounds like you want to look at the [userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent) value.

Comment: Thanks guys exactly what I wanted.